# WWW server reports error after POST Request by Internet Direct components in Delphi

Tags: delphi, post, cookies, indy, delphi-xe4

I'm using Delphi XE4 and i usually use Indy with IdHttp.POST to POST request to websites,

This time, whenever i try to POST the request i get `Error: Your browser is not sending the correct data.`

I'm very sure that I'm POSTing the right data, and i'm using the IOHandler and CookieManager.

Been dealing with this for days(literally)

Here is the code(the site in the code):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var s, lge, Kf1, Kf2, Kf3, Kf4 : String;
    lParam                     : TStringList;
begin
  S := http.Get('https://www.neobux.com/m/l/');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
  getParamLge(s,lge,'lge');
  GetInput(s,Kf1,'id="Kf1"');
  GetInput(s,Kf2,'id="Kf2"');
  GetInput(s,Kf3,'id="Kf3"');
  GetInput(s,Kf4,'id="Kf4"');


  lParam := TStringList.Create;
  lParam.Add('lge='+lge);
  lParam.Add(Kf1+'=USERNAME');
  lParam.Add(Kf2+'=PASSWORD');
  lParam.Add(Kf3+'=');
  lParam.Add(Kf4+'=');
  lParam.Add('login=1');


  memo1.Lines.Add(http.Post('https://www.neobux.com/m/l/', lParam));
end;
```

(the getParamLge and GetInput function, are just simple copy and pos functions to extract value from the GET respone).

I thought maybe it needed cookies so i've added this in the beginning:

```
  Cookie.CookieCollection.Clear;
  Cookie.CookieCollection.AddClientCookies('CFID=21531887; CFTOKEN=20369251; dh=20130709111845,1920x1080,{ts ''2013-07-09 06:18:58''}; __utma=90161412.436822896.1373368451.1373368451.1373368451.1; __utmb=90161412.11.10.1373368451; __utmc=90161412; __utmz=90161412.1373368451.1.1.'+'utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __asc=06ff77ad13fc32381fd1f5d6405; __auc=06ff77ad13fc32381fd1f5d6405; __atuvc=4%7C28; MS=flat');
```

But all in vain.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to bypass that error, and login to the site with IdHTTP

Comment: @yassine_hell most probably those cookie values that you show there are not constants but are randomly generated on any new load of the page, so they would be different on every attempt to log in

Comment: You don't *by-pass* the error; you *fix* the problem. And you do that, obviously, by sending the correct data. So send the correct data. It's clear that nobody reading this question *believes* that you're really sending the correct data. If you want help from anyone, you'll need to prove what you claim. You'll also need to ask an on-topic question; "please debug my code for me" is not on topic here.

Comment: no its not a "debug my code for me" question, cause the delphi code is working fine, but the site part is not working, which im not very good at.

Comment: If the Delphi code is "working fine," then it must be the server code that's wrong, because it's reporting bad data for what you claim is good. So go fix the server. Why is there only Delphi code in this question when the Delphi code isn't the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm very sure that I'm POSTing the right data

Since it does not work - obviously you do not (or Delphi does not - that makes no difference for server).

You should start usual debugging loop:

1. Observe reference working behaviour.
2. Observe your program behavior
3. Spot the difference
4. Eliminate the difference
5. Check if the program works now
6. If not - go to step 2.

Reference implementation would be some `WWW browser` working with site: Opera, Chrome, Firefox, MS IE, etc.

- Observing tool would be some `HTTP Sniffer` like WireShark or OmniPacket or Microsoft Net Monitor or else, however this tinkers with OS work on rather deep level.
- Or it can be local proxy with GUI, like Proxomitron or Membrane Monitor - but that would require special setup for both the program and the browser, to route their traffic through that local proxy.

Then you should read about HTTP, starting with shallow observation at Wikipedia and then opening related RFC documents (specifications of different part of HTTP protocol) so that you would understand what do the observed differences mean and how to fix them. For example many people use POST request when they actually should use GET request or such.

You want to debug HTTP program but for this HTTP logs, workign and borken, are required and your question lacks them. More so, most probably you can fix it your self, just bring your program's HTTP log to accordance with both RFCs theory and working browsers practice.

Comment: At first thanks for your reply, but ofcourse i've observed the HTTP traffics and logs, thats how i knew the input parameters in the first place, i use FireFox plugins, Live HTTP Headers and Tamper Data. And everything seemed alright.

Comment: Yassine, how did you use Firefox to confirm that *your* program sends the right data? Those plug-ins only let you work with what *Firefox* sends and receives. Is your program routing its traffic through Firefox, somehow?

Comment: LiveHTTP works from inside the browser, it might not show details like MIME Encapsulation of locale-dependent data, because it works after MIME was already unrolled (for input) or not yet applied (for output). The "it seemed alright" tells *nothing* to any of us. What information can we get from that? Obvious that if server reacts differently then something is different in traffic. Then publish the difference, no one can jump inside your head to see it, if you do not tell it.

Comment: @RobKennedy actually even "what Firefox *intends* to send and receive". Mozilla addons work inside JavaScript+XUL framework, and i think JS is not used for binary transformations but rather gets textual data after C HTTP stack reconstructed it.

Comment: Absolutely use Wireshark, or at least Fiddler.  You need to see the raw data that is *actually* being transmitted on the wire, not what a browser plugin *thinks* is being transmitted.

Comment: No, i did not use the plugin for the delphi application, i logged in the site normally, and i just captured the request with the live HTTP headers, it works all the times, only on this site, and was wondering can the cookies be the problem? and can i capture on the HTTP get??

Comment: @yassine_hell Thats why you need to make a wireshark/fiddler trace and compare the GET request from your application and your browser. I am sure you will find differences like the User Agent and other headers.

Comment: @yassine_hell what LivePlugin shows you is internal browser's information - it is its intentions, not necessarily a real data being sent. You should set some local-proxy or capturing kind of sniffer and compare real data passing, not yours or LiveHTTP's imaginations what that data should be. IF your imagination was correct - it would work already, but it does not. That means don't trust your imaginations and do look what actually happens. Also i repeat - coockies would be different for every time you load the page, you can not hard-code cookies into the program, you should calc new ones.

Comment: OK so i tried to sniff with Wireshark, but the site uses HTTPS, so i can't capture a thing with WireShark, even if i do, it would be encrypted :/

Comment: so try some proxy, that can maintain HTTPS due to its Man-in-the-middle nature. I used Proxomitron in Win98/2000 time but it does not work in Win7x64. I used Membrane Monitor though it takes some time to understand it. Fiddler2 is widely recommended as a decent tool, and it looks like it, but i failed to understand and effectively used it. But if you met SSL, then you should set MITM local proxy:  Application or Browser -> HTTP -> local proxy with sniffer -> SSL/TLS/HTTPS -> server

Comment: ^+1 proxy server with own private key is the way to go. Then you can use the same key to decrypt the https traffic in wireshark.