# IdHTTP.Put Error: HTTP/1.1405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, put, http-status-code-405, idhttp

In Delphi XE2, I am trying to upload the lines of a memo to a file on my webspace with IdHTTP.Put:

```
procedure TForm1.btnUploadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  StringToUpload: TStringStream;
begin
  StringToUpload := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    StringToUpload.WriteString(memo.Lines.Text);
    // Error: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed.
    IdHTTP1.Put(edtOnlineFile.Text, StringToUpload); 
  finally
    StringToUpload.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But I always get this error message:

[image]

So what must I do to avoid the error and make the upload?

Comment: See the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546558/
"whatch how it works and do the same"

Comment: "The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the HTTP server does not support the `PUT` method on that URL (if at all). There is nothing you can do about that.  You will likely have to upload your data another way, usually involving `POST` instead, or a completely different protocol, like FTP.

BTW, when using `TStringStream` like this, don't forget to reset the `Position` if you use the `WriteString()` method:

```
StringToUpload.WriteString(memo.Lines.Text);
StringToUpload.Position := 0;
```

Otherwise, use the constructor instead:

```
StringToUpload := TStringStream.Create(memo.Lines.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I use FTP now. What would you use? (The string could have a length between 300 - 3000 Bytes).

Comment: It is not a matter of what I would choose to use, but what the server actually supports.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above code, here is perhaps a little more information with a little helper function to assist with that Stream constructor which I found works for any string you pass through, even it contains binary stuff.

```
  //Helper function to make JSON string correct for processing with POST / GET
  function StringToStream(const AString: string): TStream;
  begin
     Result := TStringStream.Create(AString);
  end;

 //somewhere in your code, I am posting to Spring REST, encoding must be utf-8
 IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json'; //very important
 IdHTTP1.Request.ContentEncoding := 'utf-8'; //which encoding?
 response := IdHTTP1.Put(URL, StringToStream(body)); //response,URL,body are declared as String
```