# How to Convert Ansi to UTF 8 with TXMLDocument in Delphi

Tags: delphi, unicode, utf-8, delphi-6, txmldocument

It's possible to convert the XML to UTF-8 encoding in Delphi 6? 
Currently that's what I am doing:

- Fill TXMLDocument with AnsiString
- At the end convert the Data to UTF-8 by using `WideStringVariable = AnsiToUtf8(Doc.XML.Text);`
- Save the value of `WideStringVariable` to file using `TFileStream` and Adding `BOM for UTF8` at the file beggining.

CODE:

```
Procedure SaveAsUTF8( const Name:String; Data: TStrings );

const
  cUTF8 = $BFBBEF;
var
  W_TXT: WideString;
  fs: TFileStream;
  wBOM: Integer;
begin
  if TRIM(Data.Text) <> '' then begin    
    W_TXT:= AnsiToUTF8(Data.Text);
    fs:= Tfilestream.create( Name, fmCreate );
    try
      wBOM := cUTF8;
      fs.WriteBUffer( wBOM, sizeof(wBOM)-1);
      fs.WriteBuffer( W_TXT[1], Length(W_TXT)*Sizeof( W_TXT[1] ));
    finally
      fs.free
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If I open the file in Notepad++ or another editor that detects encoding, it shows me UTF-8 with BOM. However, it seems like the text it's not properly encoded.

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

UPDATE: XML Properties:

```
XMLDoc.Version := '1.0';
XMLDoc.Encoding := 'UTF-8';
XMLDoc.StandAlone := 'yes';
```

Comment: As I don't know much about unicode, since that my problems with this started just now, i would appreciate if you recommend me some beginner books or papers about it.

Comment: does http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/XMLDoc_TXMLDocument_SaveToFile.html save file okay ?

Comment: It saves the file but the webservices says that it is not encoded in UTF-8, also, Is it normal appear strange characters in the editor?

Comment: `WideString` is `Microsoft OLE BSTR` type which is UTF-16 by definition. Show `AnsiToUtf8` declaration, what is its return type ? you should use the same type for variable, otherwise text conversion happens. And since your output while declared ANSI would hold UTF-8 text, that means you're misleading Delphi and provoking it to make ANSI->Tf-16 conversin over non-ANSI text

Comment: "It saves the file" so check it using tools like Hex Editor, WinCmd Lister, UniRed, notepad++ or any other similar told - is it REALLY utf-8 or not. No matter what the service tells you - you should not trust it blindly. PS D6 was quite buggy release. Are you sure you installed all the updates ? and perhaps you'd think of upgrading to CodeTyphon now...

Comment: ansitoutf8 returns utf8string = type string, should I use a string variable instead?

Comment: "And since your output while declared ANSI would hold UTF-8 text, that means you're misleading Delphi and provoking it to make ANSI->UTF-16 conversion over non-ANSI text".  If it declared `UTF8String` - then your variable should be `UTF8String`. For code self-documenting and for future compatibiltiy, if nothing else.  PS. use sources highlighting please. In comments as well as in the question. Thanks.

Comment: What are the types? What type is `WideStringVariable`?

Comment: "Save the value of WideStringVariable to file using TFileStream and Adding BOM for UTF8 at the file beggining." where's the code ? http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: when you post the comment you press some button near the comment. Look what links are there near the button.

Comment: `widestringvariable` is `WIDESTRING`

Comment: given declaration of `W_TXT` as `BSTR` newer Delphi would give you compilation warning at ` W_TXT:= AnsiToUTF8(Data.Text);` line. I wonder if D6 left this behind a radar. So now make `W_TXT` type match the return type of `AnsiToUTF8`. Additionally i think you'd save the file directly from `TXMLDOcument.SaveToFile` and check if it is UTF8 or not.  Well, just repeating  myself actually

Comment: @DavidHeffernan @Arioch Thanks a lot, only with `encoding = 'UTF-8'` really worked, the problem is in the webservices. Can you please provide some links to unicode docs? I would appreciate a lot.

Comment: `if TRIM(Data.Text) <> '' then  W_TXT:= AnsiToUTF8(Data.Text);` bad style. you check one string and then convert anotheer potentialyl different string; if you want to `trim` - do it before the `if` in some buffer variable that you'll later use. // `fs.WriteBUffer( wBOM, sizeof(wBOM)-1)` bad style: size should be just "3", unrelated to (potentially different) variably sizeof. And you better declare `const cUTF8 : array [1..3] of byte = ($EF,$BB,$BF);` and writeBuf `cUTF8[1]` - without intermediate assignment ot a variable of another type. Again for future compat + lesser chance of mistyping

Comment: unicode.org and wikipedia.org // " problem is in the webservices. " not necessarily. It might be with passing the data into HTTP stream - you already did mis-convertion without noticing it, you may do it twice. So take soem HTTP sniffer or monitoring proxy, take HTTP RFC - and check oif you communicate with services write or not

Comment: "to sucessfuly upload into a WebServices in Delphi" is a separate question. You fused two question into one, but this is q+a site, not the forum...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the file using standard `SaveToFile` method over the `TXMLDocument` variable: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/XMLDoc_TXMLDocument_SaveToFile.html

Whether the file would be or not UTF8 you have to check using local tools like aforementioned Notepad++ or Hex Editor or anything else.

---

If you insist of using intermediate string and file stream, you should use the proper variable. `AnsiToUTF8` returns `UTF8String` type and that is what to be used. 
Compiling `WideStringVar := AnsiStringSource' would issue compiler warning and

It is a proper warning. Googling for "Delphi WideString" - or reading Delphi manuals on topic - shows that `WideString` aka `Microsoft OLE BSTR` keeps data in UTF-16 format. http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/l/aa071800a.htm
Thus assignment `UTF16 string <= 8-bit source` would necessarily convert data and thus dumping `WideString` data can not be dumping `UTF-8` text by the definition of `WideString`

```
Procedure SaveAsUTF8( const Name:String; Data: TStrings );
const
  cUTF8: array [1..3] of byte = ($EF,$BB,$BF)
var
  W_TXT: UTF8String;
  fs: TFileStream;
  Trimmed: AnsiString;
begin
  Trimmed := TRIM(Data.Text);
  if Trimmed <> '' then begin    
    W_TXT:= AnsiToUTF8(Trimmed);
    fs:= TFileStream.Create( Name, fmCreate );
    try
      fs.WriteBuffer( cUTF8[1], sizeof(cUTF8) );
      fs.WriteBuffer( W_TXT[1], Length(W_TXT)*Sizeof( W_TXT[1] ));
    finally
      fs.free
    end;
  end;
end;
```

BTW, this code of yours would not create even empty file if the source data was empty. It looks rather suspicious, though it is you to decide whether that is an error or not wrt the rest of your program.

---

The proper "uploading" of received file or stream to web is yet another issue (to be put as a separate question on Q&A site like SO), related to testing conformance with HTTP. As a foreword, you can readsome hints at [WWW server reports error after POST Request by Internet Direct components in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546558)

Comment: *however that part of webservice is unnecessary* I think it is not. The webservice checklist demonstrated a number of "check points" thus giving you directions for future investigation of the problem. Every option there is not saying "you've overlooked it, fool" but "you may have problem here, check this too". Well, up to you.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have the correct encoding inside the document, you should set it by using the Encoding property in your XML Document, like this:

```
myXMLDocument.Encoding := 'UTF-8';
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand. If it's already set that way, then why is this marked as the solution? What *else* did you have to change in your code to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to call the `SaveToFile` method of the document:

```
XMLDoc.SaveToFile(FileName);
```

Since you specified the encoding already, the component will use that encoding.

This won't include a BOM, but that's generally what you want for an XML file. The content of the file will specify the encoding.

---

As regards your `SaveAsUTF8` method, it is not needed, but it is easy to fix. And that may be instructive to you.

The problem is that you are converting to UTF-16 when you assign to a `WideString` variable. You should instead put the UTF-8 text into an `AnsiString` variable. Changing the type of the variable that you named `W_TXT` to `AnsiString` is enough.

The function might look like this:

```
Procedure SaveAsUTF8(const Name: string; Data: TStrings);
const    
  UTF8BOM: array [0..2] of AnsiChar = #$EF#$BB#$BF;
var
  utf8: AnsiString;
  fs: TFileStream;
begin
  utf8 := AnsiToUTF8(Data.Text);
  fs:= Tfilestream.create(Name, fmCreate);
  try
    fs.WriteBuffer(UTF8BOM, SizeOf(UTF8BOM));
    fs.WriteBuffer(Pointer(utf8)^, Length(utf8));
  finally
    fs.free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: not merely "that you had already done" but "that did not (alone) solved the problem"

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
procedure SaveAsUTF8(const Name: string; Data: TStrings);
var
  fs: TFileStream;
  vStreamWriter: TStreamWriter;
begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create(Name, fmCreate);
  try
    vStreamWriter := TStreamWriter.Create(fs, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      vStreamWriter.Write(Data.Text);
    finally
      vStreamWriter.Free;
    end;
  finally
    fs.free;
  end;
end;
```