# How can I use Tidhttp to make a Get request with a parameter called xml?

Tags: delphi, http, delphi-2010, indy

I've been successfully using Delphi 2010 to make an http get requests, but for one service that expects a parameter called 'xml' the request fails with a 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request' error.

I notice that calling the same service and omitting the 'xml' parameter works.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
HttpGet('http://localhost/Service/Messaging.svc/SendReports/PDF?xml=<?xml version="1.0"?><email><message><to>email@internal.com</to><from>from@internal.com</from></message></email>&id=42&profile=A1');
```

...

```
function TReportingFrame.HttpGet(const url: string): string;
var
  responseStream : TMemoryStream;
  html: string;
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  try
      try
        responseStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
        HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
        HTTP.OnWork:= HttpWork;
        HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml; charset=utf-8';
        HTTP.Request.ContentEncoding := 'utf-8';
        HTTP.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
        HTTP.Request.CharSet := 'utf-8';
        HTTP.Get(url, responseStream);
        SetString(html, PAnsiChar(responseStream.Memory), responseStream.Size);
        result := html;
      except
        on E: Exception do
            Global.LogError(E, 'ProcessHttpRequest');
      end;
    finally
      try
        HTTP.Disconnect;
      except
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Calling the same url with the parameter name 'xml' renamed to anything else, like 'xml2' or 'name' with the same value as above also works. I have also tried multiple combinations of the charset, but I think the indy component is changing it internally.

**EDIT**

The service expects:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "SendReports/{format=pdf}?report={reportFile}&params={jsonParams}&xml={xmlFile}&profile={profile}&id={id}")]
```

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: OT: you could call the `TIdHTTP.Get` overload which returns string and assign it directly to the `Result`. That will allow you to remove the currently leaking stream part.

Comment: Done. Any advice on the text/xml charset/bad request issue?

Comment: 1) Show the specifications of services, how does it expects the parameter to be passed ? /// 
2) Do you have any reference demo program like WWW browser that can call that service with success ? /// 3) try to encode all non-valid characters using percent-hex encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url#List_of_allowed_URL_characters /// 4) try to pass your xml as encoded-word base64 stream http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word

Comment: Sorry, yes. I can call the URL above from a web browser. I can call it from .Net applications with the identical URL, just not from Delphi. It's the presence of the parameter called 'xml' that causes problems from Delphi only.

Comment: URLEncode results in HTTP 500 server error

Comment: u still did not show the specificatiosn of that parameter... Okay, upt to you. since you have the working implementation - make the Delphi app behavior towards this service match those of working programs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546558/

Comment: read HTTP RFC.  HTTP.Request.Content* are fields that describe the body of the content for PUT operations or when the server sends you the body. They basically tell server to wait for the xml document AFTER the request headers (which you don't send). I think they are not valid in your case. But  again - see what other clients do and act the same, having an eye in HTTP RFC

Comment: Fiddler is proxy - you should configure your web services clients to pass their http traffic through fiddler

Comment: And the downvote because? The whole point of asking a question is to get help from experienced users. If you don't understand the problem it's ok not to engage. There is something clearly wrong with how the Indy component is handling requests with a parameter called 'xml' (Fiddler is successfully making the call with the URL from delphi)

Comment: click on the "0" karma - there si no downvote - there is 0/0. Probably someone retracted his early given +1. Still you can pass your Delphi traffic via Fidler2 or MembraneMon proxy and see what actually is sent there. And/or you can uppdate Indy to last snapshot. And/or try other HTTP libs for Delphi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to encode the parameter data when passing it via a URL, `TIdHTTP` will not encode the URL for you, eg:

```
http.Get(TIdURI.URLEncode('http://localhost/Service/Messaging.svc/SendReports/PDF?xml=<?xml version="1.0"?><email><message><to>email@internal.com</to><from>from@internal.com</from></message></email>&id=42&profile=A1'));
```

Or:

```
http.Get('http://localhost/Service/Messaging.svc/SendReports/PDF?xml=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode('<?xml version="1.0"?><email><message><to>email@internal.com</to><from>from@internal.com</from></message></email>') + '&id=42&profile=A1');
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Turns out the http 500 error was genuinely coming from the server with: A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client. I've modified the web.config file accordingly