# Delphi get http response

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, webrequest

I am trying to send and get response from url  in delphi

I am using WinInet

Here is function i am  using

**edit** : i can successfully send and get response problem is website not recognize sent data of edt1 and replay invalid response i have posted below working code of vb10 that code work perfect is there any difference in that code and mine or where i am doing wrong ?

```
  in button1

    var
    s:= string;
    begin
    s:= GetUrlContent('website url ' + edt1.text);
    memo.lines.add(s);
    end; 



function GetUrlContent(const Url: string): string;
    var
      NetHandle: HINTERNET;
      UrlHandle: HINTERNET;
      Buffer: array[0..1024] of Char;
      BytesRead: dWord;
    begin
      Result := '';
      NetHandle := InternetOpen('Delphi 5.x', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);

      if Assigned(NetHandle) then
      begin
        UrlHandle := InternetOpenUrl(NetHandle, PChar(Url), nil, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);

        if Assigned(UrlHandle) then
          { UrlHandle valid? Proceed with download }
        begin
          FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), 0);
          repeat
            Result := Result + Buffer;
            FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), 0);
            InternetReadFile(UrlHandle, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BytesRead);
          until BytesRead = 0;
          InternetCloseHandle(UrlHandle);
        end
        else
          { UrlHandle is not valid. Raise an exception. }
          raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot open URL %s', [Url]);

        InternetCloseHandle(NetHandle);
      end
      else
        { NetHandle is not valid. Raise an exception }
        raise Exception.Create('Unable to initialize');
    end;
```

**but same request when my firend makes with vb10
that works perfect**

here is his code example in vb

```
Dim httpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("web-site url" + TextBox2.Text), HttpWebRequest)
httpWebRequest.ContentType = TextBox2.Text.Trim()
Dim httpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(httpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
Dim text As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
Richtextbox1.text = text
```

**what i am doing wrong ?**

Comment: You're passing malformed URL to your function. `s:= GetUrlContent('website url ' + edt1.text);` should be `s := GetUrlContent(edt1.Text)`

Comment: yes i am doing it right- i must send url + edt1.text
s:= geturlcontent('Here goes the website url'+edt1.text); // its url + edt1.text

Comment: Then state so in your question, so we don't take a guess. Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: i see in his code he is using ContentType maybe thats where i m doing wrong how can i do that in delphi - thx

Comment: Try changing the user agent (first parameter) of the `InternetOpen` function to something like this `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0`

Comment: I thought the problem is that you're reading data in `array of Char` buffer, which in newer versions of Delphi (D2009+) would represent unicode characters, but if you're in D7, that obviously wouldn't be the problem then. Code in the answer works good for me btw, when I try to get http://www.google.com url. Just had to change buffer from `Char` to `AnsiChar` since I tested with XE2.

Comment: @RRUZ thx for you replay 
i have used same function lots of time worked perfect always 
this time it works but in reponse i cannot get correct data 
did you saw vb10 code posted at the end of first post
in that code he is using httpWebRequest.ContentType  i think there i am doing wrong can you pls check that code and confirm ?

Comment: @dudey, but do you try changing the user agent?

Comment: @RRuz yes i did try and same 
also i updated first post and explain more clear can pls check first post again

Comment: `GetUrlContent()` function works fine. Problem lies elsewhere, and you haven't provided enough information to us to see where the problem is.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546558/ - you have to read the traffic content of BOTH programs (between programs and server, real traffic from EXE's ) and notice the differences then eliminate them. Your programs behave differently - make them behave the same.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I'm not sure what's wrong with your code but if you're end goal is to load the content from a web page into a memo when why not just use

```
Uses IdHTTP;

function getContent(url: String): String;
var
http : TIdHTTP;
begin
 http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
   try
     Result := http.Get(url);
   finally
     http.Free;
   end;
end;

Memo.Lines.Add(getContent('http://websiteurl.com'));
```

Comment: thx everyone for help 
after alot search
my problem was solved from this thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856133/how-can-i-use-tidhttp-to-make-a-get-request-with-a-parameter-called-xml

Comment: when running this it seems to freez up..maybe too much on the site?