# Delphi TIdHttp Post Json Error

Tags: json, delphi, indy, idhttp

I'm trying to make a post using the **IdHttp**, sending data in json format, except that in every way I tested gives error on the server, the same data has successfully submitted for testing POSTMAN tool

```
strPost := '{...}'; //string json
xUrlPost := 'url...'; //url to post
```

TIdHttp configuration

```
IdHTTPLibSys.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
IdHTTPLibSys.Request.AcceptCharSet := 'UTF-8';
IdHTTPLibSys.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization: Bearer xToken');
IdHTTPLibSys.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('ClientInfo: 528533378');
```

using TStringList

```
JSonToSend3 := TStringList.Create;
JSonToSend3.Add(strPost);
sHtmlResp := IdHTTPLibSys.Post(xUrlPost, JSonToSend3);
```

**ERROR: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error**

using TStringStream

```
JsonToSend := TStringStream.Create(strPost, TEncoding.UTF8);
sHtmlResp := IdHTTPLibSys.Post(xUrlPost, JSonToSend);
```

**ERROR: HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity**

using TMemoryStream

```
JsonToSend2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
JsonToSend2.Write(strPost[1], Length(strPost) * SizeOf(strPost[1]));
JsonToSend2.Position := 0;
```

**ERROR: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error**

Recalling that the same data posted via POSTMAN (chrome) does not occur error, the json is correct, any ideas?

Comment: To find the difference capture the Indy HTTP request with a proxy (Fiddler2) and compare it with the successful request

Comment: id-WHAT ? `make a post using the IdFtp` ???  FTP and HTTP are totally different protocols and components!

Comment: General framework (as mjn suggested, more details) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546558

Comment: Put a component "IdLogDebug" and worked the events "OnReceive" and "OnSend" the "TIdConnectionIntercept" to see what was leaving and returning, using "TStringList" and "TMemoryString" the json not exit properly, since using "TStringStream" the json is posted in full, plus get "HTTP / 1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity" but I get the json data in Buffer (TIdBytes) of "OnReceive" event, any idea in this case? thank you again!

Comment: As mjn suggested, it would be better to troubleshoot this issue using Wireshark or Fiddler, because they will show you the working request from Postman/Chrome so you can compare it to the non-working request from TIdHTTP and see differences between them.  Using IdLog... components will not do that for you.

Comment: maybe you could use SuperObject or lkJSON or mORMot or other proven library to generate correct JSON payload

Answer (score 1):

Posting a `TStringList` sends the data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, which is not what the server is expecting.

Using a UTF-8 encoded `TStringStream` will work just fine. The 422 reply does not mean a problem occurred with the post itself, it means there was a problem with the JSON data and the server could not process it. You likely have a syntax error in the JSON.

Using a `TMemoryStream` will also work fine. However, you are writing the JSON string as UTF-16 instead of encoding it to UTF-8.  You can use Indy's `WriteStringToStream()` function for that, eg: `WriteStringToStream(JsonToSend2, strPost, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);`

Comment: The json is correct, so that sending via POSTMAN get the OK and return the data. with IdHttp, the error occurs 442, but the data that I should receive from the Post answer, I can get at the "OnReceive" the "IdConnectionIntercept", therefore the server could read the json somehow.
I made the change to `WriteStringToStream (JsonToSend2, strPost, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);` and still the same error